# How to change input from keyboard and display changed data in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

I have an input element in my HTML code and I input some value with keyboard. Then I change this values with `onkeypress` handler and display both keyboard's values and changed values.

How can I change this to only show the changed value?

```js
function dialogTrigger(event) {
  var keyboardInput = event.which;
  keyboardInput = keyboardInput + 5;
  var changedInput = String.fromCharCode(keyboardInput);
  $("#fake-search").val($("#fake-search").val() + changedInput);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fake-search" onkeypress="dialogTrigger(event)" class="fake-search" type="text" />
```

Comment: I just want to change input value when writing and see immediately. this code can change code but show changed value and unchanged value.

Comment: I only want to see changed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prevent event default behaviour:

```js
function dialogTrigger(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //<<-- here e.g
  var keyboardInput = event.which;
  keyboardInput = keyboardInput + 5;
  var changedInput = String.fromCharCode(keyboardInput);
  $("#fake-search").val($("#fake-search").val() + changedInput);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fake-search" onkeypress="dialogTrigger(event)" class="fake-search" type="text" />
```

Comment: Simple, but effective solution!